# Can't get my Javascript file to run when viewing my HTML file

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to implement my javascript code to implement a show more and show less function when the description of my page goes over a character limit. However when trying to run the site, it just shows all of the text entered in the description and it doesn't seem as though the script file is running at all. I'm wondering if it may be due to not placing the script file in the html code correctly?

Here is a snippet of my html:

```
 <div class="newsletter_titles">Weekly Economic Financial Commentary- <strong class="newsletter_description_brief">Description of newsletter</strong>
     <span class="more"> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. </span>
 </div>
```

...and my script code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // Configure/customize these variables.
    var showChar = 100;  // How many characters are shown by default
    var ellipsestext = "...";
    var moretext = "Show more >";
    var lesstext = "Show less";

    $('.more').each(function() {
        var content = $(this).html();

        if(content.length > showChar) {

            var c = content.substr(0, showChar);
            var h = content.substr(showChar, content.length - showChar);

            var html = c + '<span class="moreellipses">' + ellipsestext+ '&nbsp;</span><span class="morecontent"><span>' + h + '</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="" class="morelink">' + moretext + '</a></span>';

            $(this).html(html);
        }

    });

    $(".morelink").click(function(){
        if($(this).hasClass("less")) {
            $(this).removeClass("less");
            $(this).html(moretext);
        } else {
            $(this).addClass("less");
            $(this).html(lesstext);
        }
        $(this).parent().prev().toggle();
        $(this).prev().toggle();
        return false;
    });
});
```

What its supposed to show:

[image]

[image]

However its showing this:

[image]

Comment: The first thing I would do is check out your browser's console and see if any errors indicate syntax mistakes or incorrect file paths.

Comment: Have you included jQuery, and checked the error console in the browser? (Usually under Developer Tools)

Comment: As told, check your console for any errors and tell us what you see. Besides that, is your javascript in your `.html` file within `<script>` tags? Or is it somewhere else? If it is, are you including it correctly?

Comment: As a suggestion, that's can be easily implement with a few lines of CSS and only one line of javascript, with a class with `text-overflow` and a js that switches between classes `more`  and `less`.

Comment: This is how I'm linking the script file in my html: <script type="text/javascript" src="dropDown.js">
 </script>

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your maybe missing the final "`}`" for closing out the document.ready function.

I pasted your code into this fiddle, And other than that the order of stuff is wrong ("Show more" is showing less, and vice versa) it seems to work when adding that closing bracket.

https://jsfiddle.net/Ltt07azx/

Comment: Still doesn't seem to be working even with the edits you've mentioned...I'm really thinking it may be due to how I'm placing my script file into my html. Does this format seem correct?:  <script type="text/javascript" src="dropDown.js"> </script> The code is in the dropDown.js file and it is placed in the same folder as my html.

Comment: Remove the Type, dont know if that alone will have an impact - but worth a shot. Have you used the Developer Tools? On chrome you can hit F12 to see it, and check the console if there is any errors loading your script. 

Report back what you see in the console :) 

In case you havent, have a look at https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/ if your using Chrome.

Comment: This also seems to work fine for me. Updated a bit to fix the more/less text issue and start it closed rather than open. https://jsfiddle.net/Ltt07azx/3/